# Coffee texture in blender

Tags: texturing, photorealism

How to create the same texture in the following images?

[image]

It's a chocolate truffle with coffee beans texture.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe try something like that:

[image]

It's a subdivided cube that I've sculpted a bit, then paint a b&w mask to get a factor between brown and light brown color, give it a bit of bump and a bit of glossiness:

[image]

Comment: I tried, thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

Following @moonboot's recipe, I wanted a few more truffles, and not all the same. So, a bit more procedurally:

- An Icosphere (to scale, at about 2cm.) is given *Subdivision* and a *Displacement* modifier, with a Voronoi texture, to give it nobbles:

[image]

- The 'Feature Weights' give quite a lot of control over the Voronoi result, and it can, further, be put through a Color Ramp in the texture panel.
- The displacement is made in 'Global' space, so the every truffle gets different nuts

[image]

- The (Cycles) material uses an *Ambient Occlusion* node to pick up the surface features, and a little translucency with sub-surface scattering.

[image]

.. not perfect, but the principle is there..

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!!! too kind :)

Comment: Not perfect - well, I guess our definitions of "perfect" vary. I thought mine is almost perfect already :-) https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzLPQ.png

Comment: Is it possible to "bake" the global displacement? Otherwise the truffels will change their shape when being moved around, won't they?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes. Apply the _Displace_ modifier. Quick way, select all chocolate objects, and _Convert To > Mesh_.  But that involves applying the _Subdiv_, too, for resolution. You could displace procedurally in the shader instead, if you needed to avoid too much geometry before render-time. Baking the displacement to an image is also possible.. and in his case, not too tricky, because the original is a sphere. (Subtract the normalized radius from the actual length of P in object-space, as an emission, and bake that.)

Comment: @ThomasWeller re: your render... "Oh, Your Excellency, you spoil us!" (UK advertising cliché)

Comment: Great! Now I am hungry….

Comment: Hi Robin, i downloaded your file because your pics looked damn delicious, i opened it in 3.1, rendered view, and i got: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAiaL.jpg do i have to tap on some magic button so that it looks like yours? or is it just because of my blender apple sillicone version? 

Comment: @Chris Ahhh. that will be because you're living on Venus... :D  ....  To keep  file-sizes down, I don't pack environment HDR textures, which here, is the only lighting. Personally, I have a folder with all the Blender env. textures linked to it, and use those for BSE answers. This one is 'interior.exr'. Find that, or one of your own, and point the World background image at it, to clear up the 'missing texture' magenta.

Comment: thank you very much. The joke is...on my gpu it looks like white chocolate, on my cpu it is ok 

Comment: @Chris Hmmmm.....GPU/CPU should be the same. Check your drivers, I guess?

Comment: No drivers on a Mac…I think?

Comment: @Chris  Oh, of course,  Mac.  You have no control :)..  OS version, Blender version. Blender pref. settings. Smething's up.