# How to create this white chocolate with cookies realistically?

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to create a white chocolate with little pieces of cookies all within the surface, kind of hidden inside.

[image: Chocolate image texture]

I have the base already of the white chocolate, but I'm not sure how to recreate these pieces of cookies, not sure if by geometry nodes, or as particles, or how to scatter them that way. And make it look kind of inside, not on the surface (as the tutorial of the sugar coat on gummies for example) where all the sugar is laying on top of the gummy, in this case, it seems to be Half way through?

Any suggestion will do :)! thanks!

[image: shader]

Comment: do you want to show the chocolate only from outside (so a shader might be enough) or should it be broken too?

Comment: If you only need shader to show surface then it could be easy to find some texture in surface imperfections or rock textures (something that has smaller and bigger of random sizes and transparency - white dots on black surface) that you could use as Fac input into MixRGB and mix chocolate cookie color with white chocolate (pr generate that texture with procedural textures

Comment: Related: [Coffee texture in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/246165/coffee-texture-in-blender)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Subsurface Scattering

Works quite nice for me with *Random Walk* SSS type ...
just keep in mind - Black chocolate **has to be joined** into white chocolate object to get into a SSS count :)

[image]

[image]

Black chocolate was originally generated by particle system (Sphere with Displacement modifier to randomise shape). Make them real and join with white object ... file became too big so I decimate it to something trivial + Solidify modifier in shared file.

Black parts should not go out of white shape (like in reality / your reference) ... so probably Geometry nodes can handle it better (or simulate with Rigid Body and let fall blacks like into a form.

---

*I wanted to upload a file but 3.x is not recognised by blend-exchange.com or pastel.org as a blend file :( ... so temporarily here* https://www.dropbox.com/s/2x2gnom94773e83/test_Chocolate_SSS_opti.blend?dl=0 ... you don't have to sign in, just close the popup window.

Comment: Wowww love it @vklidu! I was testing another approach but this one looks really nice!! and seems to blend really well with the chocolate itself! it even looks getting lost deep in the chocolate height :)! love it!

Comment: how did you managed to get all of those pink spots? just by adding the principled volumetric it only shows some kind of volumetric fog within my shape, but not pink shapes generated across the surface. you did something else? any noise texturing? or something else? not working for me :(

Comment: For the _Subsurface Scattering_ method I would recommend setting the _Principled BSDF_ to _Christensen-Burley_ instead of _Random Walk_ (like in your Volumetric example). In my experience the result looks better and renders faster.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann ... Hm ... in this case only Random Walk worked for me as I expected.

Comment: @vklidu You're right... _Christensen-Burley_ looks terrible... and is extremely slow, it rendered three times slower on my PC. A few weeks ago I used it for some milky fluid in a glass and it looked better and was faster than _Random Walk_ and _Random Walk (Fixed Radius)_. Strange...

Comment: The only thing that doesn't look so good is the extreme blue tint - I think it looks more like the original chocolate if you "invert" the _Subsurface Radius_ to R/G/B = 0.1/0.2/1.0 instead of the default 1.0/0.2/0.1 values. But I just tested it on a simple Suzanne with the default _Principled BSDF_ again... Christensen-Burley looked good and rendered less than 7 seconds, Random Walk looked okay and took 31 seconds to render. I don't get it. Must be the chocolate chips in there...?

Comment: thank you really much @vklidu! I managed to understand better what you did with your example, thanks again! :D Now I'm struggling is with the geometry nodes in order to keep the cookie pieces within the volume of the chocolate itself, kind of complex to understand hehehe